# Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE: obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target

Tags: xcode

You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64

How to solve this ?

Comment: For those who is looking for an answer recently, using Xcode 14, [bitcode is deprecated.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73219854/9631529) Also see: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34148#issuecomment-1177912774

Answer (score 61):

**What is Bitcode?**
Bitcode refers to the type of code that is sent to iTunes Connect which allows Apple to use certain calculations to re-optimize apps further. You can learn more about bitcode[here](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devbbdc5ce4f).

Either: "obtain an updated library from the vendor"

or: "disable bitcode for this target."

To disable Bitcode, go to the **Build Settings** tab of your workspace, scroll down to **Build Option**s, and set Enable Bitcode to **No**.

the latter can be done through the build settings:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to enable bitcode and still make the vendor library work ?

Comment: if your vendorlib isnt bitcode I am afraid I dont see a way

Comment: Guys what about Package.swift projects?

Comment: For me, the right options was here: Targets -> <target> -> (All, Combined) -> Build Options -> Enable Bitcode -> Debug: No/Release: No

Answer (score 3):

Put `config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'` in the `post_install do |installer|` section of podfile in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a Unity problem. Solution. Set "Enable Bitcode" to "yes" in Build Settings -> Build Options on all pod targets ("Pods" project and select all targets at once).

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it should be set to "No" in UnityFramework