# Xcode 14 - Cannot code sign because the target does not have an Info.plist file

Tags: cocoapods, xcode14

I am using **cocoapods** in my project and it was working fine but after upgrade to Xcode 14 it is giving different kind or errors.

Firstly it was asking for bit code and later asked for the development team which I resolved using following script in podfile

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      #config.build_settings['BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE'] = 'bitcode'
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings["DEVELOPMENT_TEAM"] = " Your Team ID "
    end
  end
end
```

After resolving those error another one has started to appear i.e.

> error build: Cannot code sign because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. Apply an Info.plist file to the target using the INFOPLIST_FILE build setting or generate one automatically by setting the GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE build setting to YES (recommended).

my pods are updated and cocoa pod version is `1.11.3`. How can i resolve this error?

**EDIT:**

Some details are mentioned [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402) but none is working for me.

Comment: Hey Hassy! Do you have any news/updates? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Hassy. Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: #Added for resolving xcode 14 cocoapods

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.respond_to?(:product_type) and target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.bundle"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end

I have added above in pod file just before the last end of pod file.

Comment: Further I have disabled the bitcode in my projects as it is not required now in most of the cases. Apple have removed it as required. I was using bit code for Dsym symbols which do not require bitcode for now. You can check details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543728/xcode-14-deprecates-bitcode-but-why

Comment: When i build it for real device all working fine. but when build for simulator it has the above issue

Answer (score 37):

I Solved it making this change:

Pods -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Generate Info.plist File = Yes

Comment: I had a similar issue and also had to do the same thing on the app project, selecting the specific build target (also select the "All" tab and use the filter box if having a hard time finding the "Generate Info.plist File" item). Changing these settings adds `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE = YES;` lines to the `.pbxproj` files that can be committed.

Comment: When i build it for real device all working fine. but when build for simulator it has the above issue

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaqey, sorry for late response... to solve that error you need upgrade your project because React-codegen have some issues, solved in 0.70.8 and in Podfile add this in post install:

      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
        t.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
      end

Answer (score 6):

This [hack](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/11402#issuecomment-1201464693)(i.e. setting `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED` to `NO` for pod's build setting) fixed for me.

Comment: Already did this but not working.

Comment: When i build it for real device all working fine. but when build for simulator it has the above issue

Comment: not working to me

Answer (score 4):

In my case I solved it adding the Info.plist path to:
Pods -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist File

Comment: Can you please let me know what exactly we need to add there?

Comment: Within Xocde, on the left navigation, select "Pods", then in the main section of XCode, Select Build Settings --> Packaging --> Generate info.plist File = Yes

Comment: When i build it for real device all working fine. but when build for simulator it has the above issue

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes a picture clarifies things that are hard to describe in words. You can enable "Generate Info.plist File" for both Debug and Release, under the Build Settings, **Packaging.**

[image: enable Generate Info.plist file for both Debug and Release]

Answer (score 0):

All the above solution not worked for me. the final solution that had worked for me is that. **Pod -> Build Setting ->** `Generate Info.plist` to **NO** And `React-Codegen` to **YES**

Comment: Generate Info.plist already = NO